# powershell - Iterate over System.Management.Automation.PSObject

Tags: powershell

As part of one of the output I am getting following object type.

> System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[System.Management.Automation.PSObject]

I have tried following, However, it's not printing anything.

```
$out=$ScriptBlock.Invoke()
Write-Host "type == " $out.GetType()
$out[0].Properties | ForEach-Object {
 $_.Name
 $_.Value
}
```

Comment: Try `$out[0].psobject.properties` and see how that strikes you.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that `$out[0]` doesn't have a `.Properties` member, or it's not an array.

Try asking PowerShell to describe what you have:

```
# see what's in this 
PS> $out

# if it's an actual array
PS> $out[0] | Get-Member
```